# Cyclic strings, hidden programs

Tags: code-golf, quine

Write 3 programs that do the following task:

Let A, B, C source codes of those three programs;

- if A runs BC is produced as output,
- if B runs CA is produced,
- if C runs AB is produced;

so each program writes a string (cycled for each program) and hides itself from it.

Additional, but essential constraints:

- standard loopholes are forbidden;
- each program must be at least 1 byte long;
- each of three programs *must* be written in a different language;

It would be nice if your submission had this format:

#### Language A (size of A) - Language B (size of B) - Language C (size of C) - Score

```
A B C
<extra stuff>
```

Winner is someone who get the minimum score, which is the sum of sizes of three programs.

Comment: It would be nicer to have the score come last (to fit with the leaderboard script)

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/golf-a-mutual-quine) [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129772/interquine-two-programs-that-output-each-other-in-a-loop-no-cheating)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend deadlines.

Comment: Any requirement about `A`, `B` and `C` being different strings? For example, can the three strings be the same? If the program prints a newline after the output, can we not count that?

Comment: It is not required `A`, `B`, `C` being different. Newlines are counted as part of output so newlines in the string are part of the program.

Comment: Maybe someone could pick up my work. I don't have time to finish :C [Fission quine with payload](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7Mz/v/X0ndx1oXDoIcvPz//wcA) (this one can't have symbols "UDRL in payload)

Comment: [Ruby,Perl,Python mutual quines](https://tio.run/##tVNNa8MwDL37V4g2JjHLTt0Oo41hsA/KoB3tYeesdKywZUmUHsrYb88sf7RxmrIc1kAcS/Z7kp6UfF1@XNf1EII0CdXLVxz5apyXm6x6i4I0Ht3EehVhl5OxIWg3FBP9TQaeCYYvHl3FqBY5cDsx/pEN7Ge6ySIU3zYEHmiOTnxG4vFJKaWX@eJpOnuE59vpYgnJ/z263l31/pXBpYRy@7pTDkzCfFshcF5QfqURCpBzdKopAwlLCEIaDiLTQML14hB@Arnqnk3AytXCylZ8Avjx97g@FNKrwQR3FdAANfanB6l7kkQzPSusolFzdOAsJiqFBjhIhWjZxHI/u4P5wxmGgDHWR7IIYxTyRDv1YaOl5nK7eLhwLfpbAyq7V/vU@BwjWYfu@1/YhnW2FLKufwE)

Comment: Is there anything to stop all three programs from just being `1` in languages that automatically evaluate and print an expression, and ignore input that isn't referenced?

Comment: I revert the question to the original state since it misleads the original question. When I say  `if A runs BC is produced as output` I mean `BC` is catenation of `B` and `C` and `A`, `B` and `C` are strings.

Comment: Trivial solutions like _lang A_ inputs `0` and outputs `00` and so on cyclically are possible but that sounds like taking advantage from that specific language hack.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99674/three-polyglots-two-period-two-quines-and-one-code-golf-challenge?rq=1)

Comment: Does outputting nothing (empty string) count? Three empty programs

Comment: "each program must be at least 1 byte long." So no empty strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish) and [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus) 47*3 = 141 bytes

```
"r75*1-47*0.@o&r84#o&]=74#]=\`/KHj '!_@#,k.'g00
```

[Try it in Befunge!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X6nI3FTLUNfEXMtAzyFfrcjCRDlfLdbW3EQ51jYmQd/bI0tBXTHeQVknW0893cDg/38A)
[Try it in ><>!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X6nI3FTLUNfEXMtAzyFfrcjCRDlfLdbW3EQ51jYmQd/bI0tBXTHeQVknW0893cDg/38A)
[Try it in Wumpus!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9fqcjcVMtQ18Rcy0DPIV@tyMJEOV8t1tbcRDnWNiZB39sjS0FdMd5BWSdbTz3dwOD/fwA)

That's right, it's the same program three times over! When run in any of the above languages, it prints the source code twice, which is the other two programs concatenated.

#### How It Works:

```
Befunge code:
  "r                               j '!_@#,k.'g00

  "   Wrapping string literal over code
   r  Reflect the pointer
  "   Wrapping string literal
                                              g00   Fetch " from cell 0,0 
                                          ,k.'      Print 47 characters
                                       _@#          If the next character is 0, exit
                                      !             Otherwise, set it to 0
                                   j '              And jump back to the beginning


Gol><> code:
  "r75*1-47*0.                \`/KH

  "             Wrapping string literal
   r            Reverse stack
    75*1-       Push "
         47*0.  Jump to cell 28,0
                              \  Continue right
                               `/K   Duplicate the top 47 characters on the stack
                                  H  Halt and output stack contents

Wumpus code:
  "r75*1-47*0.@o&r84#o&]=74#]=\

  "r75*1-47*0.  Exact same function as the ><> code, but with a bouncing string literal
                              \  Reflect left
                            ]=   Push a copy of the " to the bottom of the stack
                         74#     Push 47
                       ]=        Push a copy of the 47 to the bottom of the stack
                     o&          Print the top 47 characters
                  84#            Push a '0' to make up for the missing 0 at the end
               o&r               Reverse the stack and print the top 47 characters
              @                  And terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

### JScript, VBScript, Windows Batch, 345 bytes

```
a=new ActiveXObject("scripting.filesystemobject");b=a.opentextfile(".js");c=b.readline();d=b.readline();a.createtextfile(".bat").write("@echo "+d.substr(2)+">.vbs\n@echo '"+c+">>.vbs")
//set a=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject"):set b=a.opentextfile(".vbs"):c=b.readline:d=b.readline:a.createtextfile(".js").write(mid(d,2)+chr(10)+"//"+c)
```

Name the file .js, then .vbs and then .bat will be created.